# Admob fix for Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, admob

Any suggestion where should I put `setInterval(showInterstitialAd, 120000);`? I'd like to use the code below to create interstitial ads every 2 minutes on my phonegap app by using admob. I use the following plugin: `<gap:plugin name="phonegap-admob" source="npm"/>`

```
var isPendingInterstitial = false;
var isAutoshowInterstitial = false;

function prepareInterstitialAd() {
if (!isPendingInterstitial) {
        admob.requestInterstitialAd({
            autoShowInterstitial: isAutoshowInterstitial
        });
    }
}

function onAdLoadedEvent(e) {
    if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL && !isAutoshowInterstitial) {
        isPendingInterstitial = true;
    }
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

    admob.setOptions({
        publisherId:          "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",
        interstitialAdId:     "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII",
    });

    document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLoaded, onAdLoadedEvent);
    prepareIntestitialAd();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function showInterstitialAd() {
    if (isPendingInterstitial) {
        admob.showInterstitialAd(function () {
                isPendingInterstitial = false;
                isAutoshowInterstitial = false;
                prepareInterstitialAd();
        });
    } else {
        // The interstitial is not prepared, so in this case, we want to show     the interstitial as soon as possible
        isAutoshowInterstitial = true;
        admob.requestInterstitialAd({
            autoShowInterstitial: isAutoshowInterstitial
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to show interstitials every once and then, because Google could consider that it is "Interstitials that unexpectedly launch" (see https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362). It is more recommended to show interstitials tied to a user action (i.e. after logging in, when a game starts or ends, etc)

That said, you should place it on `onAdClosed`. See a complete example on how to integrate it here: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/showInterstitialAd

```
function onAdClosed(e) {
  if (isAppForeground) {
    if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL) {
      setTimeout(admob.requestInterstitialAd, 1000 * 60 * 2);
    }
  }
}
```